# Hangs/Random crashes on MFC, VC++, multi threaded application

Tags: visual-c++, random, mfc, crash

I work on a MFC application. The users report that the application crashes randomly. The crashes occur during different phases while running the application and are not reproducible (The application might be crashing for multiple reasons like UI, inconsistent data, threading issues).

How can I go forward about debugging these issues.

Comment: You can run your application under [Application Verifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371695.aspx). This usually reveals a good number of issues. If all else fails, ship your application with a watchdog program, that writes a minidump (see [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360.aspx)) whenever there is an uncaught SEH exception.

Comment: Have you run a debug build of the app under the debugger? You must do this and analyze all problems/crashes. When the debugger stops the app for a problem there is a gold mine of information available by studying the debugger stack window, and clicking on it to navigate to the layers of your code that led to the problem.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP: There is absolutely no requirement at all to do this with a debug build, and it would be foolish to test something that's different from the application that shipped. Generating debug symbols for a release build is all that's needed. You will get that very same *gold mine of information* with a minidump taken from a crash on a client's machine (depending on the amount of data you gather). You do not have to ship debug symbols for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple threads that share data, you need to provide synchronized access to the data. You have to deal with synchronization issues related to concurrent access to variables and objects accessible by multiple threads at the same time. Otherwise you'll end up having unpredicted behavior including app crashes. So please guard your data using `CCriticalSection` and similar objects.

Here is an example:

```
CSingleLock lock(&m_CritSection);
lock.Lock();

m_Data = data;

lock.Unlock();
```

Comment: In my application, every thread has its own copy of the data. I don't think critical sections are causing the issue. I am not sure about the root cause and I want to know if there is a way to proceed in such a case.

Comment: Add detailed logging to your app or even better go to the customer site with debug version of your app.